# Regular expression not working as expected - JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regex ***`"location in \\((.*?)\\)"`***

against the following string: ***pro 300\nlocation in ("aaa","bbb")***

according to online regex test for java, the result should be ***"aaa","bbb"*** but when I run that in java code like this:

```
conditions.replaceAll("location in \\((.*?)\\)", "$1");
```

I get ***pro 300"aaa","bbb"***

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your regex can match only part `location in ("aaa","bbb")` so only this part can be replaced leaving `pro 300\n` untouched. Why do you expect result to be only `"aaa","bbb"` (or did I misunderstand you)?

Comment: The result is doing what you asked it to. Its matching `location in ("aaa","bbb")` then replacing it with capture buffer 1, which is `"aaa","bbb"`. The result is `pro 300"aaa","bbb"`. Not sure what the `\n` is doing there. If you want to get result of `"aaa","bbb"`, you'd have to use something like `.*?location in \\((.*?)\\).*`

Comment: Thanks  sln, I am rather new with regular expressions and that was very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replaceAll()` is replacing the part of `conditions` matched by `group(0)` of your regex.

To retrieve only the part inside `(...)` you need to use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("location in \\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(conditions);
if (m.find())
{
    String s = m.group(1);
}
```

This will retrieve the inner bracket of your regular expression `(.*?)`

Comment: I think that this is a better regex for the case location in \((((?!\)).)*)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to Rossiar's answer, if you don't want to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and just want to use `replaceAll` method then **your code is working as expected**, you have below string:

```
pro 300\nlocation in ("aaa","bbb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ and you replace this by "aaa","bbb"
```

So, your final string is:

```
pro 300\n"aaa","bbb"
```

### String.replaceAll

If you want just to get `"aaa","bbb"` using `replaceAll`, you will have to match the complete string by using:

```
conditions = conditions.replaceAll(".*location in \\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
                                    ^--------- Note ---------^
```

Or for your specific string you could use:

```
"pro 300\nlocation in (\"aaa\",\"bbb\")".replaceAll(".*\\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
```

I can't test it right now if `\n` is not being matched by `.*`, so in case it isn't then you can replace multilines by using `single line` flag or doing a regex trick:

**Single line flag**

```
"pro 300\nlocation in (\"aaa\",\"bbb\")".replaceAll("(?s).*\\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY3qI6/2)**

**Regex trick**

```
"pro 300\nlocation in (\"aaa\",\"bbb\")".replaceAll("[\\s\\S]*\\((.*?)\\)[\\s\\S]*", "$1");
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY3qI6/1)**